# Can't convert string to int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently started using python 3 from python 2. In Python 2 the strings typecasting could be done easily using `int()` function but I am having problem in Py3.5.3

```
current = input("Enter the Current price: ")
int(current)
print (type(current))
c = current - 24
```

current is still shown as `Class str` even after the typecast function.

Error is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

I know this is a just a small error but the examples I have looked up on net are all using the int function like I used. What could be the problem here

Comment: That line, `int(current)`, would have no effect in Python 2 either, since you're not saving the result (and variables don't carry type, if that's what you thought; objects do). It looks like the actual problem is [the change in `input` between 2 and 3](/q/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python-3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not saving the return value from `int(current)`, which is the integer representation. Try

```
current = int(current)
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is incorrect. `int` hasn't changed between Python 2 and 3, it's `input()` that changed. Python 2 equivalent of `input()` is `raw_input()`. In Python 2, `input()` evaluates the input and so `return`s an `int` here

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll remove that last part in the answer.